# Check if logging is set up

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Is there a way to check if logging has already been set up? I have a module I'm working on and I want it to be able to log but only if the parent script already has a logger set up. One way to do this would be to pass the parent script's logger object directly to the module and have it default to `False` and then have all of the log statements wrapped in an `if logger` block but I'd prefer to not require the user to pass anything. Ideally, `logging.getLogger(__name__)` would throw an error if run in the module when the parent script didn't have a logger set up but that is not the case.

Comment: The docs provide suggestions about how to use logging in a library: https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library. That may have some useful information for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `import logging` it sets `logging._startTime` - so you can do something like:

```
import time
now = time.time()
import logging
if logging._startTime < now:
    print("Logging imported earlier.")
```

This is a private variable though, so might not be the best option as there's no guarantee of it existing in future versions.

Alternatively, if you have added handlers or made other modifications to a logging instance, you can see these if you use the same name later, e.g.:

```
import logging

x = logging.getLogger('foo')
x.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
y = logging.getLogger('bar')
z = logging.getLogger('foo')

for i in x, y, z:
    print(i.handlers)
```

Result:

```
[<logging.NullHandler object at 0x7f2affa62a90>]
[]
[<logging.NullHandler object at 0x7f2affa62a90>]
```

calling `addHandler` also adds a reference to the handler to `logging._handlerList` but again this is private, and doesn't let you know which handler was added by which instance.